# Clear instructions on how to integrate grunt-mutation-testing

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner, mutation-testing

I'm trying to use this mutation testing tool called grunt-mutation-testing, but with no success.

It's unclear to me from the readme file (on GitHub, or npmjs) how the tool recognizes the test code, versus the production code. Moreover, I don't understand what their example is doing (since there's no documentation for it).

Any help would be appreciated. I would like to use this tool, but currently, trying to set it up is causing more pain that it's probably worth.